# Can't execute some python commands for virtual env from Fish shell

Tags: python, shell, fish

I'm on MacOS Sierra and have python3 and python installed via brew. Using the command `python3 -m venv my_venv`, I created a vitual environment for python3. I then tried to activate it with `. bin/activate.fish` from within `my_venv`. However I get the exception

```
$(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(automate_stuff)'.
bin/activate.fish (line 58):         if test -n "$(automate_stuff) "
                                                 ^
from sourcing file bin/activate.fish
    called on line 175 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/HEAD/share/fish/config.fish

in function '.'
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file 'bin/activate.fish'
```

Also I tried to install flake8 for the `my_venv` with the command (from within my_venv) `. bin/pip -m pip install flake8`. That also failed with

```
Missing end to balance this if statement
bin/pip (line 9): if __name__ == '__main__':
              ^
from sourcing file bin/pip
    called on line 175 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/HEAD/share/fish/config.fish

in function '.'
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file 'bin/pip'
```

What is going on and how do I fix it? Just to repeat I run Fish Shell as my default shell.

Comment: Haven't permission  or wrong path identification.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in virtualenv. `$()` isn't (and never was) valid fish syntax, yet it's in the fish script. Please try to report it there.

Answer (score 0):

> . bin/pip -m pip install flake8.

Here you are sourcing (the `.` command is an alias for `source`) the pip script with fish. Since `pip` is a python script, you'll get syntax errors.

You want `./bin/pip`.

> $(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(automate_stuff)'.

This is a bug in virtualenv - `$()` isn't valid fish syntax.